# Excel formula with % in Javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get the following Excel sum working in Javascript.

=H21*(1+H22)*(1+H23)

H21 is a base price like 6.4
H22 and H23 are a negative percentage like '-15%'.

H22 and H23 come from range sliders so I have them like '-15'.

For now I have:

```
let price = H21*(1+H22)*(1+H23);
```

Adding % signs obviously don't work. Why does this work in Excel and not in Javascript and how can I re-factor to do this in Javascript. Any lead on documentation would also be very nice!

Comment: `Why does this work in Excel and not in Javascript`  That's like saying, why do I have to change gear in a manual car, and I don't have to in an automatic.   Percent, means per 100, or IOW: divide by 100.   `H22/100`

Comment: In Javascript, `%` is used for Modulo - so, the Javascript `5%2` is the same as the Excel `=MOD(5,2)`, while in Excel `%` means "Divide by 100 and change General formatting to Percentage formatting" - so Excel `2*15%` is Javascript's `2*15/100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A percentage can be expressed as a float from 0-1, so I think you could just divide your percentage figures (H22 + H23) by 100:

```
let price = H21*(1+(H22/100))*(1+(H23/100));
```

Using numbers with % symbols in JS won't work, because the sum will cast them as floats by dropping anything that isn't valid:

```
parseInt('15%') // 15
```

Excel is seeing the % and doing something a bit more clever (which I didn't previously know about).

Comment: Excel is slightly clever, but not completely clever - `=10+15%` will output `1015%` rather than `11.5`.  **But**, while Excel doesn't know what to do with a permille symbol (‰) or permyriad/basis point (‱), you *can* chain `%` symbols: `=5%` is `0.05` and `=5%%` is `0.0005` which is the same as basis point (frequently used in finance e.g. for loans/bonds)

Comment: @Chronocidal - Did not know that %% worked- thanks. But why should 10+15%=11.5 rather than 10.15 =1015%?

Comment: @CharlesWilliams If you use a decent calculator, then "10+15%" is treated as "10\*1.15" - i.e. "10 + (10\*15%)".  What would *you* say 15% more than 10 was?

Comment: @AdamHopkinson Thanks! Was way to focused on the Excel formula. Feeling a bit simple now.